# errorCallback in $http.get().then is never called

Tags: angularjs

I use the the simplest $http.get().then construction, but errorCallback is never called (checked with 500 and 404 error code)

```
$http.get(url,{cache: pageCache}).then(
        function(data){
                console.log('getPage.SUCCESS');
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.data);
        },
        function(data){
                 console.log("ERROR");
                 console.log(data);
        }
);
```

[HTTP HEADERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEqq2.png)

I also tried success/error - but the same issue is arrised

Comment: could that be because of cache? What happens when you remove `{cache: pageCache}`? Otherwise your code looks good

Comment: You do request from `http://localhost:8000` to `http://127.0.0.1:8091`?

Comment: @David Votrubec Checked - problem is not in cache

Comment: @LinnTroll Yes, what is wrong with it?

Comment: I found one [aticle](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/AngularJS-HTTP-Service-Success-Handler-400-Response-Code-and-Interceptors/), but such interceptor also didn't help

Comment: @anastsiacrs this is cross-domain request, you can not do that. You success function is work?

Comment: @LinnTroll  Yes, it is

Comment: try using catch: .then(....)['catch'](someHandlerFunction),  var someHandlerFunction = function() { .... };   
tell me if that works for you.

Comment: @Nizar No, it didn't help too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/AngularJS-HTTP-Service-Success-Handler-400-Response-Code-and-Interceptors/), interceptor's responseError function have to be ended with return $q.reject(rejection);

One of my interceptors didn't follow this rule and cause all this mess

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are using the .then function which returns an object called response that contains several objects one of which is data.

The following is an example from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

The response object contains a status object, angular uses this to run either the success callback or the error callback.

Then to access your data object use response.data, or what I like to do is have a service that returns only what I need to avoid confusion in the controller.